# No Markdown editor in django admin pages

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin, blogs

I am using django 1.8.6 and python 3.6 for creating a blog app . I am quite new to both.   I have installed  **django_markdown** for getting the markdown functionalities and the toolbar in the admin pages.
But even after including necessities  in **setting.py** and **urls.py** , I'm not able to get those nice Markdown editor.

My admin.py file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django_markdown.admin import MarkdownModelAdmin
from . import models


class EntryAdmin(MarkdownModelAdmin):
   list_display = ("title", "created")
   prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("title", )}

admin.site.register(models.Entry, EntryAdmin)
```

Thanks in advance for your time and effort.It would be great help if you inform me what the problem is.

Comment: Have you added `url('^markdown/', include( 'django_markdown.urls')),` inside your `urls.py` ?

Comment: Yes i have added the same

Comment: You have declared one of your model fields as `MarkdownField()`, right?

Comment: I have tired doing so but i didn't `MarkdownField()` in `django_markdown.field` or inline `django.models`.

Comment: `from django_markdown.models import MarkdownField`

Comment: It worked .Thanks alot @nik_m .

Comment: Glad I could help. I created an answer in order for this question to be closed, as answered!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you declared one of your Model fields as [`MarkDownField`](https://github.com/klen/django_markdown#id6) ?

Like this:

```
from django_markdown.models import MarkdownField

class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = MarkdownField()
```